# Checkbox selection based on name is prompting other checkbox options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am attempting to set the value of `newStatus` or `usedStatus` if any of the options for either is selected, but for only the ones that are selected.

As of now, if you select "New mowers" and then click on one of its options, you will see in the console that `New Selection1` and `Used Selection` is displayed in the console. For this example and the functionality, only `New Selection1` should be showing.

The following if statements are controlling it:

```
if ("input:checkbox[name=newMowerOption]:checked") {
    newStatus = '1';
    console.log('New Selection' + newStatus);
}
if ("input:checkbox[name=usedMowerOption]:checked") {
    usedStatus = '1';
    console.log('Used Selection' + usedStatus);
}
```

You can see that I am checking for the specific checkboxes based on the name, so I am unsure why if you select a new mower option that the used is also selected.

Anyone have an idea?

```js
var newStatus = ''; //Telling whether new is selected
 var usedStatus = ''; //Telling whether used is selected
 var newSelPush = '';
 var usedSelPush = '';
  
 $('.equipmentOptionCont').change(function() {

  var newSel = [];
  var usedSel = [];

  //Get new mower options
  $("input:checkbox[name=newMowerOption]:checked").each(function(){
   newSel.push($(this).val());
   newSelPush = newSel.join(', ');
  });
  //Get used mower options
  $("input:checkbox[name=usedMowerOption]:checked").each(function(){
   usedSel.push($(this).val());
   usedSelPush = usedSel.join(', ');
  });
  //Find out if new/used mower option is selected and then create variable showing 1 if true
  if ("input:checkbox[name=newMowerOption]:checked") {
   newStatus = '1';
   console.log('New Selection' + newStatus);
  }
  if ("input:checkbox[name=usedMowerOption]:checked") {
   usedStatus = '1';
   console.log('Used Selection' + usedStatus);
  }
  $('#newSel').html(newSelPush);
  $('#usedSel').html(usedSelPush);
 });

 $('#newAllOptions').click(function() {
  $('input[name=newMowerOption').toggle().prop('checked', true);
 });
 $('#usedAllOptions').click(function() {
  $('input[name=usedMowerOption').toggle().prop('checked', true);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>New Mowers</label>
  <input type="radio" name="notifymethod" id="newMowerSelect" class="equipmentMainSel">
  <label>Used Mowers</label>
  <input type="radio" name="notifymethod" id="usedMowerSelect" class="equipmentMainSel">
  <div id="newMowerOptions" class="equipmentOptionCont">
      <p>New Mower Options</p>
   <label>Ferris</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="newMowerOption" value="Ferris">
   <label>Wright</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="newMowerOption" value="Wright">
  </div>
  <div id="usedMowerOptions" class="equipmentOptionCont">
      <p>Used Mower Options</p>
   <label>Toro</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="usedMowerOption" value="Toro">
   <label>John Deere</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="usedMowerOption" value="John Deere">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed logic to get the desired results.

```js
var newStatus = ''; //Telling whether new is selected
var usedStatus = ''; //Telling whether used is selected
var newSelPush = '';
var usedSelPush = '';
  
$('.equipmentOptionCont').change(function() {

 var newSel = [];
 var usedSel = [];

 //Get new mower options
 $("input:checkbox[name=newMowerOption]:checked").each(function(){
  newSel.push($(this).val());
  newSelPush = newSel.join(', ');
 });
 //Get used mower options
 $("input:checkbox[name=usedMowerOption]:checked").each(function(){
  usedSel.push($(this).val());
  usedSelPush = usedSel.join(', ');
 });
    var radioSelID = $("input:radio[name=notifymethod]:checked").attr('id');
    if(newSel.length && radioSelID == "newMowerSelect") {
        newStatus = '1';
     console.log('New Selection' + newStatus);
    }
    if(usedSel.length && radioSelID == "usedMowerSelect") {
        usedStatus = '1';
     console.log('Used Selection' + usedStatus);
    }

 $('#newSel').html(newSelPush);
 $('#usedSel').html(usedSelPush);
});

$('#newAllOptions').click(function() {
 $('input[name=newMowerOption').toggle().prop('checked', true);
});
$('#usedAllOptions').click(function() {
 $('input[name=usedMowerOption').toggle().prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>New Mowers</label>
<input type="radio" name="notifymethod" id="newMowerSelect" class="equipmentMainSel">

<label>Used Mowers</label>
<input type="radio" name="notifymethod" id="usedMowerSelect" class="equipmentMainSel">

<div id="newMowerOptions" class="equipmentOptionCont">
    <p>New Mower Options</p>
    <label>Ferris</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="newMowerOption" value="Ferris">
    <label>Wright</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="newMowerOption" value="Wright">
</div>

<div id="usedMowerOptions" class="equipmentOptionCont">
    <p>Used Mower Options</p>
    <label>Toro</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="usedMowerOption" value="Toro">
    <label>John Deere</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="usedMowerOption" value="John Deere">
</div>
```

---

**Old answer:**

Your `if` statements were just checking a string, which in JavaScript was always returning `true` and thus both were being printed. I changed it to check the actual property instead, there a couple different ways to do this but the following does what you want.

Comment: This only works if you select the first checkbox option of each.

Comment: I changed the logic a little, does it work for you now?